# How I change Bootstrap order on mobile layout for multiple sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Page like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3"> Left Sidebar </div>
   <div class="col-md-6"> Body </div>
   <div class="col-md-3"> Right Sidebar </div>
</div>
</div>
```

So if I look at it on a mobile Device, the left sidebar is on top, but I want the Body on top. Is this possible. I tried it with push an pull, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Place them as you want in mobile and then use col-md-pull-xx and col-md-push-xx

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-push-3 col-md-6"> Body </div>
      <div class="col-md-pull-6 col-md-3"> Left Sidebar </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"> Right Sidebar </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxtjr39b/6/)

Comment: Similar to mine :D

Comment: Yes, lucky I'm :D at least this one !

Comment: @kodikotriftis answer is good for mobile view. but at laptop view body and left sidebar not visible these go to much left side.

Comment: is there any solution for laptop view? These column  remain at same position as in question picture.

Comment: @FarooqAhmad put more text or a background color and you will see, that they take more space than what you see with just a "body" word